# Dumping the stored checksum of a file in Artifactory using jfrog CLI

Tags: artifactory

Using the jfrog CLI (jfrog rt s) I can dump file information of my repo to stdout, but this information does not contain the stored checksum. I see a similar question 
"Artifactory CLI - Jfrog - How to get binary Hash code (SHA1, SHA256) through jfrog CLI" but the answer is only about searching for a specific checksum. Not being very familiar with jfrog at all, can someone suggest a simple method (has to use jfrog please) for dumping the checksum info for all or a specific file in the repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 1.36.0 of JFrog CLI, the search command also returns the SHA1 and MD5 of the files. For example:

```
$ jfrog rt s repo/path/file
```

Answer (score 1):

The `jfrog rt search` command theoretically supports returning sha256 sums if you're using jfrog-cli version 1.36.0 or greater, Artifactory server 5.5 or greater, and a [correctly configured database](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Checksum-Based+Storage#Checksum-BasedStorage-BasedStorage-SHA-256Support).

Under the hood, the `jfrog rt search` command utilizes [AQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-SpecifyingOutputFields) to generate a query which it sends to the server.  The default query performs items.find().include(*), which returns all of the supported fields.  I guess if the database isn't set up right then SHA-256 sums aren't supported (this seems to be the case at my workplace).

Fortunately, there's an alternative which works even on old versions of the jfrog-cli (I've tested this with 1.26.2).  This involves utilizing the `jfrog rt curl` command to directly grab the metadata from the server.  Note that the `jfrog rt curl` command doesn't support the standard `--url` `--access-token` or `--apikey` parameters, so you'll need to configure a connection to the server using `jfrog rt c` first (don't forget to use `--interactive=false` if you're automating this).  Once you've done that, the magic incantation which you're looking for is:

`jfrog rt curl -XGET "api/storage/your_repo/your_file"`

This will return a JSON blob like the following:

```
'{
  "repo" : "your_repo",
  "path" : "/your_path/your_file",
  "created" : "2020-07-21T21:28:20.663Z",
  "createdBy" : "token:your-token",
  "lastModified" : "2020-07-21T21:28:27.277Z",
  "modifiedBy" : "token:your-token",
  "lastUpdated" : "2020-07-21T21:28:27.287Z",
  "downloadUri" : "https://your_artifactory_url/artifactory/your_repo/your_path/your_file",
  "mimeType" : "application/x-gzip",
  "size" : "1198168",
  "checksums" : {
    "sha1" : "5e288fe94da1fed0b4ce6695c7a984426e9f5a78",
    "md5" : "a012711241ba3a5bd4a04e833001d490",
    "sha256" : "d22e76b6cc0b4e2e29076d08f8209dec2b7d9c28e71a13d989175a1272ac3da7"
  },
  "originalChecksums" : {
    "sha1" : "5e288fe94da1fed0b4ce6695c7a984426e9f5a78",
    "md5" : "a012711241ba3a5bd4a04e833001d490",
    "sha256" : "d22e76b6cc0b4e2e29076d08f8209dec2b7d9c28e71a13d989175a1272ac3da7"
  },
  "uri" : "https://your_artifactory_url/artifactory/api/storage/your_repo/your_path/your_file"
}'
```

The `originalChecksums` are from when the artifact was first uploaded.  If the artifact has been tampered with on the server then the regular `checksums` may be different.  For this reason I'd recommend validating against the `originalChecksums` unless you're operating in an environment where the same artifacts are expected to be overwritten.

If you're looking for a quick and dirty way to extract the returned checksums from the JSON blob then try this ugly hack I threw together in bash (note that this won't work if you collapse the whitespace first):

```
#!/bin/bash
...
checksums=($(sed -n -E "s/^\\s+\\\"sha256\\\"\\s:\\s\\\"(.*)\\\"\$/\\1/p" <<< "$response"))
checksum="${checksums[0]}"
original_checksum="${checksums[1]}"
```

If you have the option, I'd recommend using a more robust json parser instead.